# add link with tpl files on admin panel in prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have created a link option in prestashop 1.6 admin panel under 
catalogue->products
under suppliars i have added a tab "test"

i have add tabe name under
controllers/admin/AdminProductsControllers

$this->available_tabs_lang = array( 'Test'      => $this->l('Test'),);line:101,120
and this will show me in under supplier section.

I have also create a tpl file under 
admin8133/themes/default/template/controllers/products/test.tpl

now when i click on test tab then a blank page will display ..please let me know how can i link that tab with template file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The admin templates are not stored in themes folder. They are in yourshop/admin/themes/